# NGINX pretty urls: No input file specified

Tags: nginx, debian, configuration

I've been struggling with a NGINX configuration. I've set up a development environment (local laptop) with a configuration supporting search engine friendly (SEF) urls, but the same configuration doesn't seem to work on my test server.

local configuration:

```
server {
server_name  example;

root   /home/arciitek/git/example/public;

client_max_body_size 500M;


location /collection/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /collection/index.php$args;
index index.php;
}

location / {
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/arciitek/git/example/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

This works fine. Now on the test environment it looks like this:

```
server {
server_name dev.example.com;

access_log /srv/www/dev.example.com/access.log;
error_log /srv/www/dev.example.com/error.log debug;
root /srv/www/dev.example.com/public;

location /collection/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /collection/index.php$args;
index index.php;
}

location / {
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/dev.example.com/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

On my development environment everything is fine. But on my test environment, when I call a url in my browser with prettyness added : collection/[brand]/[product]. I get the:
`No input file specified`
error. Mind you, if I call a url ending with collection/ everything works fine..

Can anyone help me with this please? if more info is needed, please let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I was having problems with my symbolic links... thanks for your help. For those of you experiencing similar issues, make sure your simbolic link in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` is pointing to the right file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to specify the SCRIPT_FILENAME separately in the PHP location block. It is already defined in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params file.

So, remove the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` line.

Also, for PHP script security, I would add:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

to the PHP location block.

Otherwise, are you sure you have the `/collection/index.php` in place?

EDIT:

As @AlexeyTen noted below, replace this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /collection/index.php$args;
```

with:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /collection/index.php?$args;
```

Comment: Hi Tero, thanks for your response, the result is the same. when I call /collection/ I get the page I expect, but when I call /collection/[brand]/[product] I get No input file specified. (I want that request to be handled by the same php file /collection/index.php)
It seems to me that the whole block is skipped, is that possible?

Comment: @ErikRos, you forgot question mark before `$args` in `try_files`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Very good point. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Add it to your answer, if you wish